# undefined is not a function (evaluating 'transform.forEach')

Tags: react-native

When I run a new react-native app in Android device I am getting this Error:

> undefined is not a function (evaluating 'transform.forEach')

I had

- node version 7.9.0
- react-native-cli version 2.0.1
- react-native version 0.44.0
- npm version 4.2.0

I use Windows 10 (64 bit).

Comment: I do believe that without seeing some code It is almost imposible to help you.

Comment: I don't have a particular code, the error exists with a simple project **hello**

Comment: what tutorial did you follow?

Answer (score 0):

After six hours spent debugging react proptype validation and then digging a level deeper into packaging internals, I figured out a [brain-dead simple solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13765#issuecomment-312609314):

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I've read a lot and tried all different answers, but  after days trying, here is what works:
- Run terminal in admin mode (I'm under windows)
- Change the directory to another with a shortest path
- Change the directory to outside dropbox
- Pushed the code from GIT (starting from zero)

I can't say what step is the responsible, but it's a little effort to do everything in the same time... And it worked!